# retrieving data from database using VB

Tags: vb.net

I have an **ASP Calendar** then what I intend to do is that when the user clicks a date from the calendar it would update the gridview below to show what are the schedule in that date, but my code throws me the **Catch ex As Exception**

```
    Protected Sub calSched_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles calSched.SelectionChanged 'Selecting a date
    schedule.Value = calSched.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString()

    Try
        con = New MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=;Uid=root;Pwd=;")
        Using cmd = New MySqlCommand("SELECT sched_id, sched_date, sched_time, dent_lname FROM schedule_table INNER JOIN dentist_table WHERE sched_date = @p1", con)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", schedule.Value.ToString)
            con.Open()
            dat = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            Dim ds As New DataSet()
            Dim a As New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)
            a.Fill(ds)
            grdSched.DataSource = ds
            While (dat.Read())
                grdSched.DataBind()
            End While
            con.Close()
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        lblMessage.Text = "Cannot recover schedule"
    End Try

End Sub
```

**Schedule.value.tostring** is an input field that updates when user clicks, any suggestion?

Schedule_table - sched_id (Primary Key, Auto Increment), sched_date(VARCHAR 25), sched_time(VARCHAR 9), dent_id(INT 6, Unsigned Zerofill, Foreign Key)

Dentist_table - dent_id(Primary Key, Auto Increment, Int 6, unsigned zerofill), dent_fname, dent_lname

Comment: If `Schedule` is a textbox, why not `Schedule.Text`

Comment: I was wrong sorry, it was input field

Comment: You don't need the reader if your using Fill, and the dataSource should be a DataTable, not a DataSet.

Comment: Yes, I tried both and still cannot recover schedule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Protected Sub calSched_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles calSched.SelectionChanged 'Selecting a date
 schedule.Value = calSched.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString()

 Try
    con = New MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=;Uid=root;Pwd=;")
    Using cmd = New MySqlCommand("SELECT sched_id, sched_date, sched_time, dent_lname FROM schedule_table WHERE sched_date = @p1", con)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", schedule.Value.ToString)
        con.Open()
        Dim ds As New DataSet()
        Dim a As New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        a.Fill(ds)
        grdSched.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
        grdSched.DataBind()
    End Using
 Catch ex As Exception
    lblMessage.Text = "Cannot recover schedule"
 Finally
    con.Close() 'this block will always run, close it here error or not
 End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: Still gives me cannot recover schedule

Comment: I don't think your SQL statement is correct, can you show the table structures?,

Comment: Typical JOINS are `Where table1.field = table2.field`

Comment: Then maybe it's the connection string, your doing yourself an injustice by not checking the exception - since your using the Try/Catch, check out the error and post that.

Comment: DataBinding System.Data.DataRowView does not contain a property with the name 'app_id', the problem was my gridview column.Why haven't I thought of that. Thank you so much.